# use parentheses in c# calculator

Tags: c#, webforms, calculator

Hello I just write a simple calculator in C# and I want to improve my program to handle parentheses.

Here is my button to add 1(digit):

```
 private void btnOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtResult.Text += '1';
        }
```

This is a method for my Plus button:

```
private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblChar.Text = "+";

            num1 = float.Parse(txtResult.Text);
            txtResult.Text = "";

        }
```

And this is for to calculate final result:

```
private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    num2 = float.Parse(txtResult.Text);


                if (lblChar.Text == "+")
                {

                    num3 = num1 + num2;

                    txtResult.Text = Convert.ToString(num3);
                }
}
```

Anyone can help me to write parentheses for my program?

Comment: hint: use Reverse Polish Notation, RPN http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: I know reserve polish, But I don't know how to write the code in c#

Comment: You can use code presented in this post, it's well explained and contains source code in c# http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35320-reverse-polish-notation-in-c%23/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) - Mathematical Expressions Evaluator for .NET

```
 Expression e = new Expression("2 + (3 + 5)*6");
 var result = e.Evaluate();
```

Comment: As you see in my code, I get lable text value to do operations. so when I want to use braces I will give me some errors. I cannot convert whole text to float or vice-versa.
Is it possible to use ncalc in my project. if it is please write code for me and update your answer. Thanks

Comment: This is using NCalc. You need to download it, add it as a reference.. then use the above example Damith has given you. Its pretty powerful and will fullfil your requirements tenfold.